# Functional Programming Solution

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I'm kind of newbie in FP and Haskell and trying to solve some trivial tasks. E.g we have array of products:

```
data Product = Product String Int
let apple = Product "Apple" 15
let pineapple = Product "Pineapple" 20
let products = [apple, pineapple]
```

The tasks:

- calculate total price of products (this is simple, e.g I can use foldl)
- calculate total price if every third apple has a discount 0.5
- calculate total price if the pineapple is free in case of buying each two apples.

In traditional imperative programming this is quite simple, e.g I can use different calculation strategies for this.
How can I solve this in Haskell? Should I use State monad or there are other solutions? Could you please provide some algorithm steps or code?

Comment: Unless the price of a pineapple/apple can change, none of these need even `State` - just filtering your list of products to get a count of all the apples or pineapples. Then it just comes down to arithmetic on those two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To do the second problem (for which the solution can be modified to solve the third problem) this can be solved pretty easily using recursion

```
totalPriceWithBuy2ApplesGet1HalfOff :: [Product] -> Int
totalPriceWithBuy2ApplesGet1HalfOff = go 0
    where
        -- It doesn't matter how many apples you've seen, the total
        -- price of 0 items is 0
        go applesSeen [] = 0
        -- If you've seen 2 apples already and the next product is
        -- an Apple, give discount
        go 2 (Product "Apple" price : products) =
            price `div` 2 + go 0 products
        -- If applesSeen is some other number and you encounter an apple,
        -- add its price and increment applesSeen
        go applesSeen (Product "Apple" price : products) =
            price + go (applesSeen + 1) products
        -- For any other product just add the price to the total and recurse
        go applesSeen (Product _ price : products) =
            price + go applesSeen products
```

This would work even when your apples aren't all the same price, although that'd be a really strange store to shop at.